# How to loop an animation of a button in Kotlin?

Tags: loops, android-studio, animation, kotlin

I would like to know how to loop the following animation of a button in Kotlin:

Example: https://ibb.co/XD7H073

As you can see in the image my goal is to constantly move the button up and down.

Here are the core parts of the code I´m trying to write:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationY", 30f).apply {
                duration = 500
                start()
            }
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationY", -30f).apply {
                duration = 500
                start()
            }
```

Thanks to the one who can show me how to put these two animations in an array and then loop the array infinitely!

//////////////////
Solution:

```
val animations = arrayOf(-140f).map { translation ->
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationX", translation).apply {
            duration = 800
            repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
            repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, you may need to play with `ObjectAnimator.REVERSE/RESTART` and/or add from value in `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(_, _, from, to)`

```
val animations = arrayOf(30f, -30f).map { translation ->
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationY", translation).apply {
        duration = 500
        repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
        repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE
    }
}

val set = AnimatorSet()
set.playTogether(animations)
set.start()
```

Comment: do you know how to delay every repetition of the animation for a couple of seconds?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is a little bit dirty, but should work.
Just add empty translation to animations array `arrayOf(30f, -30f, 0)`.
If you want some tweaks (custom duration), then just add at the end of animations array   
`ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(_, _, 0f, 0f).apply{
    duration = 1000
    repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
}`

Comment: @ Stanislaw Baranski look I updated my question. Can you think of something else because the delay doesn`t work?